# What is the convention for creating applications users in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a `users` model for my application sign in with Mongoose / MongoDB. Based on how I see it when I deploy to Atlas or Mlab, it auto generates a `users` collection but for the purpose of database authentication - like this user has read access, write access, admin, etc. What is the convention for creating application users? Do I also use the same `users` collection but add additional schema properties or do I make a different one altogether like `app_users`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `test` or `admin` database? You should create a new database for your application. When you create a new database it will not come with any predefined collections or such, so you can start blank (which is what I assume you want?).

You don't need to explicitly create a new database. Just point your driver to a database name you want for your app. Or in the `mongo` CLI type `use myAppDb` and you can start adding collections there.

More details here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#working-with-the-mongo-shell